# Original exception text was: 'Category' object has no attribute 'answer'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Please check the error.Much appreciate if you can help:

error:
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `answer` on serializer `CategorySerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Category` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Category' object has no attribute 'answer'.

model.py:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    question_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}-{self.question_text}'

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='questions_answer')
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer_text

class Category(models.Model):
    category_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_text
```

serializer.py:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'

class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ques=QuestionSerializer(source='questions',read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = '__all__'

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # question=QuestionSerializer(read_only=True,source='question.question')
    answer=AnswerSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['id','category_text','answer']
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        answer_data = validated_data.pop('answer')
        category = Category.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for answer_data in answer_data:
            Answer.objects.create(**answer_data)
        return category
```

views.py

```
class QestionAnswer(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    def perform_create(self,serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your code, in `CategorySerializer` you are specifying the `fields` attribute in the `Meta` class like

```py
class Meta:
    model = Category
    fields = ['id','category_text','answer']
```

The problem here is that the fields included here need to be part of the model `Category`. In `models.py` the `Category` class has no `answer` field. A solution for that would be to change the `Category` model to:

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    category_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_text
```

You will probably need to add a default value to perform the migrations correctly. Hope it solves the problem!